# Qt Android: How to call Toast.makeText from Java?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I want to call Toast.makeText method from Java in Qt / C++. Codes:
I added QT += androidextras in .pro file.

**Toast.java:**

```
package com.classes.java;

public class Toast {
  public static void makeText(String text, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration).show();
  }
}
```

**toast.h:**

```
#ifndef TOAST_H
#define TOAST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAndroidJniObject>

class Toast : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Toast(QObject* parent = 0);
  Q_INVOKABLE void make_text(QString& text, int duration);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // TOAST_H
```

**toast.cpp:**

```
#include "toast.h"

Toast::Toast(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Toast::make_text(QString& text, int duration)
{
  QAndroidJniObject txt = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(text);
  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
      "com/classes/java/Toast",
      "makeText",
      "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V",
      txt.object<jstring>(), duration);
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>

#include "toast.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  qmlRegisterType<Toast>("java.class", 1, 0, "Toast");
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0
import java.class 1.0;

Window {
  visible: true

  Toast {
    id: toast
  }

  Button {
    id: button
    text: "Click Me!"
    onClicked: toast.make_text("Hello World!", 2000)
  }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
UserPath\build-QtMobileTest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Release\android-build\src\com\classes\java\Toast.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration).show();
                   ^
  symbol:   method getApplicationContext()
  location: class Toast
Note: UserPath\build-QtMobileTest-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Release\android-build\__qt5__android__files__\src\org\qtproject\qt5\android\bindings\QtActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I think I need android context for getApplicationContext() but I do not know how can I get context? How can I call Toast.makeText method using Qt / C++ JNI? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must extend QtActivity class. and call runOnUiThread for calling android Toas class. First create android java class:

```
package org.qtproject.example.mytoast;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyToast extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static MyToast m_instance;

    public MyToast ()
    {
        m_instance = this;
    }

    public static void makeText(final String message)
    {            
        m_instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       Toast.makeText(m_instance.getApplicationContext(),
                                      message,
                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                });
    }
}
```

now in cpp class use this code for calling MyToast.makeText method:

```
QString toastMessage = "Your toast message!!!";
QAndroidJniObject myToast= QAndroidJniObject::fromString(toastMessage );
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/mytoast/MyToast",
                                       "makeText",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       myToast.object<jstring>());
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the context, you will need a activity. This means you will have to extend the default Qt activity and make it accessible to your Toast class.

This document explains how to use the jni with Qt. On page 42 there is an example of an overriden `QtActivity`:

https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf#page=42

```
// src/com/kdab/training/MyActivity.java
package com.kdab.training;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity;

public class MyActivity extends QtActivity
{
    // we'll need it in BroadcastReceiver
    public static MyActivity s_activity = null;

    // every time you override a method, always make sure you
    // then call super method as well
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        s_activity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        s_activity = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this code and I added AndroidManifest.xml but I get same error. I don't know well Java. So I don't understand codes on the web page. Can you help me? Should I do then?